# Getting apparmor to profile a program inside docker container

Tags: docker, apparmor

I'm looking to profile a service running inside a specific docker container. I went through the documentation of aa-genprof and aa-autodep and both take program as input to profile. I can't seem to find a way to point those programs to profile a binary inside the docker container.

I tried mounting the directory of the program inside the container and then referencing that program, but its logs are not captured in audit.log. Thoughts?

Is there some other way I can build a profile for that docker container?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the shortcoming you are facing with `aa-genprof` - it distinctly takes a program path. Additionally you may set a profile to use [complain](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/apparmor-utils/aa-complain.8.en.html) mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like [bane](https://github.com/genuinetools/bane) to create the custom profile for the apparmor

Comment: To use bane we need to know the accesses the program needs. In my scenario, I don't have a comprehensive list of all accesses and syscalls the program needs.